# Difference between USERENV('SESSIONID') and USERENV('SID)?

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I am trying to understand what is the difference between SID and Sessionid in Oracle. How do they generate these, does it represent Process id or it is something internal to Oracle? Is there anything equivalent in PostgreSQL?

```
SQL> select userenv(‘SID’) from dual;

USERENV('SID')
--------------
           258

SQL> select userenv('SESSIONID') from dual;

USERENV('SESSIONID')
--------------------
          4294967295

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any detailed Oracle documentation about SESSIONID usage and role (documentation only says "auditing session identifier" but nothing more). There is no such thing in PostgreSQL.

The SID is the general session identifier that should be used with the SERIAL# (see V$SESSION) but is different from V$PROCESS.PID.

In PostgreSQL there is no session identifier but only the backend process identifier (pg_stat_activity.pid).